# Need help in deciphering Kobold naming rules from Pathfinder Advanced Races Compendium

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kobold

The book link: http://paizo.com/products/btpy9jeb/discuss?Advanced-Races-Compendium

I like Kobold characters concept a lot, and I'm introducing them as NPC in my campaign. But I just can't understand this name creation rule...

> Kobold names usually consist of a given name and a sobriquet, or descriptive name.
>
> \begin{array}{| ll | ll |} \hline
> \text{Name} &  & \text{Sobriquet} &  \\ \hline
> \text{Root} & \text{Suffix} & \text{1st half} & \text{2nd half} \\ \hline
> \text{An} & \text{o(m)} & \text{Scrap} & \text{lure} \\
> \text{Ik} & \text{ta(f)} & \text{Bronze} & \text{egg} \\ \hline
> \end{array}

What would those two names look like? Ano Scraplure and Ikta Bronzegg? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Hi @Piotr, and welcome to the site. I've edited your post to present the table in text; we reserve code formatting for actual code. I think I've captured everything in the original; you can always find the version you started with by checking the post's revision history (click "edited $TIME ago"). If you want to make changes to the table's presentation hopefully the source makes it clear how to tweak it, or you can find some tips on how to use MathJax [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6336/23970). Happy gaming!

Comment: @nitsua60 thanks :) I couldn't find how to make such tables, but now I have a great example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Nicholas Milasith](http://koboldpress.com/author/?authorname=Nicholas%20Milasich), from Kobold Press, the [Sobriquet](https://koboldpress.com/sobriquets-of-the-kobolds/) is a *"fake name"* that describe some action or event on the kobold's life, that is used to define who he is. This is not the real name of the kobold, but is a name that he is known for among others of his race, and the name that he gives to other races, as they probably can't pronounce his real name correctly anyway.

> The too-talls shake their hairy heads at the bizarre array of names that kobolds call themselves. Kobolds see this as an opportunity to trick and confuse their rivals, of course. Most kobolds share only their sobriquet with other races and are not afraid to **make up a new one on the fly if necessary**. This does not help them with their own kind, who give honest, but sometimes cruel, sobriquets to their fellow kobolds. A sobriquet can define a kobold: Guttersneak is shifty, Goldscale is noble.
>
> (...)
>
> A kobold looking to redeem herself must literally make herself a new name: by actions, not words!

There is also a [Kobold Name Generator](http://www.koboldpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/KoboldNameGen_v1036.zip) provided by Kobold Press, with a .csv file containing a table with 100 different entries for each column, which is randomized by the application.

That table has surnames prefixed with (m) and (f) for males and females. So, whenever you feel like creating a new name, all you have to worry about is the surname (Suffix) being the correct gender, others can be randomized at will. The prefix (Root) can be randomized freely, and the same can be done for the two parts of their Sobriquet (these are gender neutral).

Given the two table entries you listed, you could end up with a male name as An**o** or Ik**o**, or a female name as An**ta** o Ik**ta**, and any variation of sobriquets.

Comment: To clarify, you're indicating that one male would be Ano, known as Scraplure, and the other example is a female named Ikta but known as Bronzegg (Bronze-egg?)

Comment: @Nicolas actually gives four examples of possible names using those entries on the table. But yes, you are correct, both are possible names and sobriquets.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the way I read these kinds of charts is to pick from each field randomly.  So Ano Scraplure and Ikta Bronzegg are both possible, but you could also get Anta Scrapegg and Iko Bronzelure, for example.